# COCOA OSX : App rename

Tags: macos, cocoa, cfbundleidentifier

I renamed my cocoa app name (CFBundleDisplayName) kept the bundle identifier the same, but there are previous versions of the old app that have been already released to the users.
I wanted to know how to delete/replace previous old app with same bundleidetifier on installing this new app. Also is there a way to replace all previously created shortcuts of the old app.

Comment: How was it released?

Answer (score 0):

## IF the app was distributed via App Store:

if the bundle identifier stays the same, the new app will replace the old.

shortcuts won't update their name though but there is nothing you can do about it

## if not, AND you are not sandboxed

in this case you can do all you like: in applicationDidFinishLaunching use the Spotlight API to find the old app and delete it AND find the short cuts and change them

this is A LOT of effort and not worth it IMO

## if not, AND you are sandboxed

no way!

Comment: This is true only if it was released via the Mac App Store, which I have a feeling it wasn't.

Comment: you're right of course - sorry - I tend to forget that there are other ways. I use brew for the rest ;)

Comment: The app was not released via App Store but hosted on our website.